# Is Bulk revision control possible?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a drive folder with say 100 png files.

Now I want to watermark every single png file  and upload new version of each. (Sorry watermarking is a an afterthought. I shall take precaution in future folders :( )

Is there any way I can upload the entire folder with new version or so? (The old folder on drive has the files that already have some metadata attached to them (like description and properties). I do not want to destroy that but want to move that to new versions of each file.)

Or otherwise what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each file recursively under your folder and upload a new blob for each file: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads